# how to make mkvirtualenv work with current directory?

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to use `mkvirtualenv .` to create a virtualenv in the current directory, but with no success:

```
~/repos/foo$ mkvirtualenv .
created virtual environment CPython3.9.5.final.0-64 in 284ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/Users/mdval/.virtualenvs, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/Users/mdval/Library/Application Support/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==21.2.3, setuptools==57.4.0, wheel==0.37.0
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator
ERROR: Environment 'foo' does not exist. Create it with 'mkvirtualenv foo'.
```

However, using `mkvirtualenv foo` works. Can someone help me, please?

Here's my `.zshrc` config:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/repos
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

`virtualenvwrapper` is intended to manage all you virtual environments. To do that it stores all virtual envs in one place — under `$WORKON_HOME`. That is, `mkvirtualenv foo` creates a virtual env in `$HOME/.virtualenvs/foo/`.

If you want to create a virtual env in a different directory that means you want to create a virtual env that is not under control of `virtualenvwrapper`. Sure, no problem, just create a virtual env using `virtualenv`:

```
virtualenv .
```

Answer (score 1):

The command you're looking for is: `mkvirtualenv env_name -a ./`. This will create a virtualenv in your current directory.

So when you do `workon env_name` it will automagically take you to the directory you specified.

For example: If I am in my `~/Repos/project/backend` and run `mkvirtualenv project_env -a ./` it doesn't matter where I'm at when I run `workon project_env` it will take me to `~/Repos/project/backend`.

Hope this helps!